# How to check Sub string condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to check sub string value on the page.

```
if ((col == 4 || col == 6) && ((text.substr(0, 1) == "%") || (text.substr(0, 1) == "@") || (text.substr(0, 1) == " "))) {
    GetVariableDescription(pageIndex, row, col, text);
}
```

When I am trying the Code with `%0012` or `%00AA` or `@1234` or `@ABDJC`
It's working good but when I am entering `AAAk` or `1234` or `ASJA`
It's not validating

Is that something I am doing wrong here? this condition is not true?

```
(text.substr(0, 1) == " ")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not validating"? The strings "AAAk", "1234" and "ASJA" do not have a "%", "@" or a " " (space) as their first character, so the if condition will be false. Do you want it to be true?

Comment: Do these values `AAAK, 1234, ASJA` contain a space as a prefix?
http://jsfiddle.net/g4CJL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously that's because the first character of `AAAk` isn't a space

```
alert("AAAk".substr(0,1)==" ");​​​​​​ //false
alert(" AAAk".substr(0,1)==" "); //true
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using === instead of ==, the double equals will also match a space with false.

Comment: That may be true in a general sense, but what does it have to do with the question? The code shown is comparing a one-character string with space, not comparing `false`...

Comment: i was thinking it would avoid a false positive in the case that text.substr failed, but you're right: it doesn't solve the examples he gave.